# transforming data using sed commands

Tags: sed, formatting

I need to transform `xxx#yyy@zzz` to look like `ZZZ xxx-yyy` using a script.
I am already using a case statement in the script, so should I use an if statement before the case statement or should I continue with the case statement?
here is my current script

```
function usage
{
  echo "usage: $0 arguments ..."
  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then echo "ERROR: $1"
  fi
}

# Script begins here
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "Joe Fosteson"
  date
  echo
   for arg
  do
    case $arg in
      rootjobs)
        echo "Root is running $(ps -U root -u root u | wc -l) processes on $(una
me)."
         ;;
      student_accounts)
        echo "There are $(ls -1 /home/student/ | wc -l) student accounts on $(ho
stname)."
         ;;
      *)
        usage  "Do not know what to with $arg"
         ;;
    esac

    echo "*****"
  done
else
  usage

fi
```

Here is the sed commands i was using but it is not correct format........

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then echo "Please enter a file name"
else echo
 if test -f $1
  then
    #s1.sh
    starting_data=$1
    sed 's/ //' $starting_data > raw_dataz
    sed "/^id/ d" raw_dataz > new
    cut -f1 -d, new > id1
    sed 's/ //' id1 > id2
    cut -f2 -d, new > lastname1
    sed 's/ //' lastname1 > lastname2
    cut -f3 -d, new > firstname1
    sed 's/ //' firstname1 > firstname2
    awk '{print $0":"}' lastname2 > lastname3
    sed -e 's/-//g' id2 > id3
    paste -d\  firstname2 lastname3 id3 > final
    cat final
  else echo "$1 cannot be found"
 fi
fi
```

Comment: That whole slew of sed+cut+awk+paste commands with intermediate files could all be done concisely with a single awk command and no temp files. If you post some sample input possible starting_data` values) and expected output (`final` contents given that input) we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string like `xxx#yyy@zzz` to `ZZZ xxx-yyy` in bash:

```
str='xxx#yyy@zzz'
if [[ "$str" =~ (.+)#(.+)@(.+) ]]; then
  str2="${BASH_REMATCH[3]^^} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  echo "$str2"
else
  echo "Bad string format"
fi
```

In sed

```
sed -r 's/(.+)#(.+)@(.+)/\U\3\E \1-\2' <<<"$str"
```

Comment: could you give me an example in a case satement?

Comment: # Script begins here
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
  echo "Joe Fosteson"
  date
  echo
   for arg
  do
    case $arg in
      rootjobs)
        echo "Root is running $(ps -U root -u root u | wc -l) processes on $(una
me)."
         ;;
      student_accounts)
        echo "There are $(ls -1 /home/student/ | wc -l) student accounts on $(hostname)."
         ;;
        transfordata)                                              xxx#yyy@zzz                                                                         *)
        usage  "Do not know what to with $arg"
         ;;
    esac

    echo "*****"
  done